# Mathematical derivation from Deep learning book

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logistic-regression

In https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/mlp.html p. 179 this derivation is made but lacks details that I need to understand it:

$P(y)= \frac{exp(yz)}{\sum_{y’=0}^{1}exp(y’z)} = \sigma((2y-1)z)$

Where $\sigma(x) =  \frac{1}{1+exp(-x)} =  \frac{exp(x)}{1+exp(x)}$

I just cannot see how they “magically” make this $(2y-1)z$ appear… please can someone kindly show me all the details of this derivation?
I tried things /tricks like multiplying by fractions equal to 1 such as $exp(…)/exp(…)$ etc. but cannot find…

P.s. I think this expression can be developed as:

$ \frac{exp(yz)}{\sum_{y’=0}^{1}exp(y’z)} =  \frac{exp(yz)}{exp(0*z)+exp(1*z)}=  \frac{exp(yz)}{1+exp(z)}$

However, I do not see how one can play with this last expression to make it equal to  $\sigma((2y-1)z)$ …

Comment: $y$ can only ever be $0$ or $1$, so you only need to check the equation for those two values. Substitute each one in turn and you will see the equation is true. I don't think it's true for other values of $y$.

Comment: Hum but how do they get the general formula with 2y-1 …?

Comment: Divine inspiration? Who knows? Does it matter as long as it's true?

Comment: The sigmoid((2y-1)z) will either be sigmoid(z) or sigmoid(-z) but by substituting y=0 or y=1 in the other eq. I would get both times sigmoid(z) hence I can never get simoid(-z) what do you think?

Comment: It does matter I would like to understand at least your substitution

Comment: $\sigma (-z) = \exp (-z) / (1 + \exp(-z)) = 1 / (1 + \exp z) = P(0)$. I don't see a probem.

Comment: Oh yes I see now. Sorry I got confused. Thanks. You are a genius.

Comment: There are these tricks when a variable takes on one of two values (e.g. 0 or 1, -1 or 1, etc.). If y can only be 0 or 1, then 2y-1 can only be 1 or -1. It's a way of making the choice of {0,1} into a choice of {-1,1}. Sometimes we want to have the latter over the former. That's my guess over why it just pops up.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to write things...
$$
P(y=0) = \frac{1}{1+\exp(z)}= \sigma(-z)
$$
$$
P(y=1) = 1-\sigma(-z) = \sigma(z)
$$
So you can write 'magically' $P(y)=\sigma((2y-1)z)$ for $y=0$ or $1$.